# On the estimation of fourier coefficients of modular forms

Tags: modular-forms

I've been reading *A first course in modular forms* by F.Diamond and J.Shurman. In chapter I, the problem 1.2.6. says:

> Let $\Gamma$ be a congruence subgroup of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$, thus containing $\Gamma(N)$ for some $N$, and suppose that the function $f:\mathcal{H}\to\mathbb{C}$ is holomorohic and weight-k invariant under $\Gamma$. **Suppose also that in the Fourier expansion $f(\tau)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nq_N^n$, the coefficients for $n>0$ satisfy $|a_n|\leq Cn^r$ for some positive constants $C$ and $r$.**

I want to know if that estimation is always feasible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [p.213-216](http://www.paris8.free.fr/Fred%20Diamond%20Jerry%20Shurman%20A%20First%20Course%20in%20Modular%20Forms.pdf). The idea is that if $f(z)$ is a weight-$k$ cusp form then $|f(z)| (\Im(z))^{k/2}$ is $\Gamma$ invariant and continuous on $\Gamma \setminus \mathcal{H}^*$, hence it is bounded on $\Im(z) > 0$, say by $C$.

Also for every $y >0$ and hence for $y=1/n $ : 
$$a_n = \int_{iy}^{iy+1} f(z)  e^{-2i \pi nz}dz = n^{k/2}\int_0^1 f(x+i/n) (\Im(x+i/n))^{k/2} e^{-2i \pi n(x+i/n)}dx \le e^{2\pi} C n^{k/2}$$

If $f(z)$ is not a cusp form, then substract the weight-$k$ Eisenstein series whose coefficients are $\mathcal{O}(n^r)$ (with $r = k-1$)

Comment: I am worried this might only be true in level 1, with counterexamples coming from higher weight forms holomorphic in $\infty$ but not in other cusps?

Comment: @user399601 I should probably say $f(z) (Im(z))^{k/2}$ is a function well defined and continuous on the compact Riemann surface $\Gamma \setminus \mathcal{H}^*$ (and hence bounded on $\mathcal{H}$) because for any $\alpha \in GL_2(\mathbb{Q})$ : $f(\alpha \cdot z)$ is a cusp form for $\alpha^{-1} \Gamma \alpha$

Comment: @user399601 If $f(z)$ is holomorphic only at the $i \infty$ cusp then you are right, but cusp form for $\Gamma$ means holomorphic at all the cusps

Comment: Check the pages.